# Python: folders usage style

Tags: python, architecture, directory, project

Imagine project that have many scripts in different subfolders.

Some scripts uses temporary folder (not a problem to reach system-wide folder), some loads resourses from other subfolder so `./..` pattern is widely used.

One could run them both in `IDE` and in console. In IDE it's easy to set current folder for all runnable scripts, but when run in console, set current dir other that runned file location is a little pain to scripts users.

What is the best way to control loading resources in `python`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, folders count is not very big, so I define `resource locator` static class. All paths calculate relatively it's file path. Any file thet need to load a resource, ask a folder from that class:

```py
import os
from enum import Enum


class ResourceType(Enum):
    ConfigFile, JobsFile, OutFolder = range(3)


class ResourceLocator:
    @staticmethod
    def get_resource(resource_type):
        file_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)

        out_folder = file_folder + "/../out/"
        config_folder = file_folder + "/../config/"

        path = ""
        if resource_type == ResourceType.ConfigFile:
            path = os.path.abspath(config_folder + "config.ini")
        elif resource_type == ResourceType.JobsFile:
            path = os.path.abspath(config_folder + "jobs.ini")
        elif resource_type == ResourceType.OutFolder:
            path = os.path.abspath(out_folder) + "/"
            if not os.path.exists(path):
                os.makedirs(path)

        return path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data as a reference for python package hierarchy setup.

Then, consider using pkg_resources in order to use those files:
http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#basic-resource-access

Anyway, you can use **file** to get the path to the package:

```
import os
this_dir, this_filename = os.path.split(__file__)
DATA_PATH = os.path.join(this_dir, "data", "data.txt")
```

Comment: How __file__ can helps to reach resource in other folder?